# Transforming perl script to python

Tags: python, perl

I have a bit silly question. I found this perl script and it works, but I do not program on perl, I prefer python. So I find it hard to modify the script for my needs. Can somebody help me transform it in python?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

die "SINTAX: $0 file_elenco file_match\n" if ($#ARGV <1);

$file1=$ARGV[0];
$file2=$ARGV[1];

%h=();
open (A,"< $file1");
while ($r=<A>){
        chomp $r;
        $h{$r}=1;
}
close A;

open (B, "< $file2");
while ($r=<B>){
#       chomp $r;
        @v=split(/\t/,$r);
        if (defined ($h{$v[1]})){
                print "$v[0]\t$v[1]\n";
        }
}
```

My attempt,

```
file1=sys.argv[0]
file2=sys.argv[1]

dictA= dict()
with open('file1','r') as f1:
    for line1 in f1:
        listA = line1.split('\t')
        dictA[listA[1]] = listA

dictB= dict()
with open('file2','r') as f2:
    for line1 in f2:
        listB = line1.split('\t')
        dictB[listA[1]] = listB
        for key in dictB:
            if key in dictA:
                print key[0]+'\t'+key[1]
```

Comment: You try first. If you get stuck, show what you have so far and explain exactly what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Do you know in layman's term what this script is trying to do? If you google that, you will find a hundred hits of python scripts doing the same thing.

Comment: @Mat, I understand you want to see my effort, but for me it is like translating from arabic language to english without a dictionary, since I never ever program on perl and not familiar with the syntax. I understand the general concept thou

Comment: I'm not actually interested too much in how much effort you put in. I'm interested in spending effort helping people if it will help others in the long run. Questions like "translate this for me" help you, and essentially no-one else - no-one will ever have the exact same code to translate, and even if they did they probably wouldn't find your question. As for your edit, it's missing the part that describes your problem now. What's missing? What's your code doing/not doing that the perl code does?

Comment: Your Python isn't an accurate transliteration.  Your Perl effectively combines your second and third loops, avoiding slurping the whole of the second file into memory (so it only stores one line at a time of the second file), whereas the Python code does read the whole of the second file into memory and then processes what it stored.  But that much should be evident from the presence of 3 loops in the Python compared with 2 loops in the Perl.

Comment: I have obviously being googling and trying to solve my problem for a week now. I would not be posting my question here if I had a complete idea. Regarding the questions,are you asking me what is the problem I am trying to solve, or lead me to see my mistakes in the code?

Comment: thank you @JonathanLeffler, I am aware it is not accurate at all, that is my very poor effort, since I know nothing about perl, but your explanation was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a literal translation of the Perl script:

```
import sys

file1=sys.argv[1]
file2=sys.argv[2]

dictA= dict()
with open(file1,'r') as f1:
    for line1 in f1:
        dictA[line1.rstrip('\n')] = 1

with open(file2,'r') as f2:
    for line1 in f2:
        listB = line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
        if listB[1] in dictA:
            print "%s\t%s" % (listB[0], listB[1])
```

By the way, in your Perl script, you do want to uncomment the `chomp $r` line, especially if the file only has two columns.